# Internet traffic classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, traffic

Recently, I have been reading some papers about Internet traffic classification particularly using Machine Learning Algorithms.

I am planing to study on it and I would like to propose a project idea on Internet traffic classification for my Machine Learning class this semester.

My first step is to collect data on my local network consisting of 3-4 clients. I am using wireshark tool to sniff the packets.

My next step is to extract TCP flows from wireshark packets. At this step, I am trying to use tcpflow on Linux. tcpflow creates different files for each flow. Here, contents of the files are mostly binary and I cannot figure out how I can extract discriminators out of these files.

Can someone give me an idea or share his/her experiences on how I can interpret the tcpflow files? I will be more than happy to hear your recommendation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas for features you can extract from TCP traffic:

- Port/protocol (Most protocols usually use the same port on the server)
- Packet frequency and size (short command packets or long streams of data)
- TCP connection phase
- Stream errors / retransmissions
- Flow control messages and rate limiting

For better feature extraction, you are probably going to have to look at the details of some of the protocols (HTTP, DNS, etc) themselves and not just the TCP streams. I think wireshark already does this, so why not reuse their library features?

You also might want to look at design of [intrusion detection systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System) (IDSs), as they are pretty much doing the same thing with traffic and trying to classify it as benign or malicious.